# Big O analysis of a sorting algorithm that counts smaller elements

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, loops

How do I prove the runtime of an algorithm with Big O notation? I don't know much about O notation, I just I know how to compare sets of functions with each other and I'm also familiar with the master theorem.

But how do I do this? Is it just $O(n^2)$ because there are $2$ loops? That doesn't sound right. The loop in COUNTSMALLER doesn't have else so it's less expensive than the other one. I just know that cnt <- 0 is $O(1)$ but I don't know exactly about the loops. Am I supposed to do something with $T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)$? I could do that if you give me $a$ and $b$ but I have to idea how to get those or if this even makes sense.

This algorithm doesn't terminate if some elements are equal btw, I guess we can assume that all elements in the array $A$ are unique.

````
SORT(A)
1 i <- 1
2 while i < len(A) do
3    j <- COUNTSMALLER(i, A) + 1
4    if i = j then
5       i <- i + 1
6    else
7       A[i] <-> A[j]
8    end if
9 end while


COUNTSMALLER(i, A)
1 cnt <- 0
2 for j <- 1 to len(A) do
3    if A[i] > A[j] then
4      cnt <- cnt + 1
5    end if
6 end for
7 return cnt    

```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: Yes that certainly helped a lot but I'm still having trouble with the while loop because i only gets incremented if i = j so this just depends on the input, I have to figure out the worst case but I'm not sure how that looks like. Let's assume we get O(x) for the while loop, is the whole algorithm O(x*n) then?

Comment: $T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)$ has nothing to do with this algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big-$O$ analysis of an algorithm consists of two part in practice.

- A quick and rough estimate, which works often.
- Rigorous analysis as well as refinement when necessary.

---

We assume that the algorithm works. That means on any valid input (i.e., no duplicate numbers), it returns the correct result in finite time.

As a first guess, the time-complexity is probably $O(n^2)$ since there is a nested loop, where each loop seems contributing a factor of $n$.

---

Now let us take a closer look.

It takes $O(n)$ time to run `COUNTSMALLER(i, A)`.
So, it takes $O(n)$ time to run line 3 to line 8, the loop body of the while loop in `SORT(A)` once.

Now the question is how many times will that loop body be run? Each time the loop body is run, either $i$ will increase by $1$ or one more position of the `A` stores the expected value. Since $i$ can increase at most $n$ times and there are $n$ position in `A`, the loop body runs at most $2n$ times. Hence it takes $O(n\times n) = O(n^2)$ to run the while loop in `SORT(A)`.

It takes less time comparatively to run all other code such as line $1$. Hence the time-complexity is $O(n^2)$.